# Python 3 'for loop' tkinter images only 1 appears

Tags: python, image, loops, url, tkinter

I am trying to iterate around a list of urls of images and display those images in tkinter. My code is:

```
root = tk.Tk()

for imgTag in outputS:
    url = imgTag["src"]
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as u:
        raw_data = u.read()
    im = Image.open(BytesIO(raw_data))
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
    label = tk.Label(image=image)
    label.pack( side = tk.BOTTOM)

root.mainloop()
```

However this displays only one of the images, but also seems to leave enough room for the other images. I am pretty sure the list of urls are correct as I have output them to the terminal and seen them.

Comment: Have you done any research before asking this question? There are several questions with answers on this site related to creating or using images in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Is the image that appears the last one?  Is so, the problem is that you rebind `im` each loop and only keep the last one.  All previous get garbage collected.  See [this](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm).  The solution is to keep a reference to each Iamge with each ImageTk widget.

```
root = tk.Tk()

for imgTag in outputS:
    url = imgTag["src"]
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as u:
        raw_data = u.read()
    im = Image.open(BytesIO(raw_data))
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
    image.im = im                  # <<< new line
    label = tk.Label(image=image)
    label.pack( side = tk.BOTTOM)

root.mainloop()
```